# HashBiMap get getting blocked

Tags: java, guava

We are using HashBiMap in our application and we created it like this

```
HashBiMap<String, String> map = HashBiMap.create();
```

and we have guava-26.0-jre version of guava.

Recently noticed our application getting hung and not able to process any other requests. Got a thread dump and noticed things like these

```
Thread.State: RUNNABLE
native=false, suspended=false, blockCount=1, waitCount=4, cpu=9h, 12m, 45s, 434ms, user=9h, 10m, 59s, 990ms
    com.google.common.collect.HashBiMap.seekByKey(HashBiMap.java:223)
    com.google.common.collect.HashBiMap.get(HashBiMap.java:254)

Thread.State: RUNNABLE
native=false, suspended=false, blockCount=1, waitCount=6, cpu=9h, 11m, 49s, 453ms, user=9h, 10m, 3s, 760ms
    com.google.common.collect.HashBiMap.seekByKey(HashBiMap.java:223)
    com.google.common.collect.HashBiMap.get(HashBiMap.java:254)

Thread.State: RUNNABLE
native=false, suspended=false, blockCount=274, waitCount=6615, cpu=22h, 31m, 29s, 966ms, user=22h, 27m, 30s, 540ms
    com.google.common.collect.HashBiMap.seekByKey(HashBiMap.java:223)
    com.google.common.collect.HashBiMap.get(HashBiMap.java:254)

Thread.State: RUNNABLE
native=false, suspended=false, blockCount=91, waitCount=2443, cpu=22h, 29m, 51s, 541ms, user=22h, 25m, 54s, 140ms
    com.google.common.collect.HashBiMap.seekByKey(HashBiMap.java:223)
    com.google.common.collect.HashBiMap.get(HashBiMap.java:254)
```

There were several other threads like above that got blocked on a call to get, but the longest that was waiting was this with cpu=22h, 31m, 29s, 966ms

```
Thread.State: RUNNABLE
native=false, suspended=false, blockCount=3, waitCount=32, cpu=5h, 46m, 7s, 733ms, user=5h, 45m, 500ms
    com.google.common.collect.HashBiMap.seekByValue(HashBiMap.java:234)
    com.google.common.collect.HashBiMap.put(HashBiMap.java:274)
    com.google.common.collect.HashBiMap.forcePut(HashBiMap.java:301)
```

There was only one thread thats waiting on the forcePut like above.

Would there be any reason for why HashBiMap.get would go into a loop to find the value for a key and never returns.

Comment: Often this kind of thing happens when multiple threads access a data structure without proper synchronization.

Comment: It the your bimap is indeed accessed from multiple threads, wrap it with [`Maps#synchronizedBiMap`](https://guava.dev/releases/29.0-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Maps.html#synchronizedBiMap-com.google.common.collect.BiMap-) to avoid such issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### TL;DR

As suggested by **Xaerxess**, uses [Maps#synchronizedBiMap](https://guava.dev/releases/29.0-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Maps.html#synchronizedBiMap-com.google.common.collect.BiMap-) in case the map is accessed by multiple threads. You never knows what can happens when there is multiple threads.

### For someone who is curious on whats happened

> Would there be any reason for why HashBiMap.get would go into a loop
>   to find the value for a key and never returns.

---

It is an interesting example on how multiple thread create "unexpected" result.
Let's take a look in line **HashBiMap.java:223**  of method `seekByKey`

```
private BiEntry<K, V> seekByKey(@Nullable Object key, int keyHash) {
  for (BiEntry<K, V> entry = hashTableKToV[keyHash & mask];
      entry != null;
      entry = entry.nextInKToVBucket) {
    if (keyHash == entry.keyHash && Objects.equal(key, entry.key)) {
      return entry;
    }
  }
  return null;
}
```

And line 223 is

```
      entry = entry.nextInKToVBucket) {
```

Blocking in this line means there is an infinite loop, which is due to circular reference of `entry` and `entry.nextInKToVBucket`.

One of the possible case is that: In the `put` method,

```
private V put(@Nullable K key, @Nullable V value, boolean force) {
  ...

  BiEntry<K, V> newEntry = new BiEntry<>(key, keyHash, value, valueHash);
  if (oldEntryForKey != null) {
    ...
  } else {
    insert(newEntry, null);
    rehashIfNecessary();
    return null;
  }
}
```

suppose unfortunately there are two calls with same key and value from two threads simultaneously, created two new entry A and B. Then in `insert` method,

```
private void insert(BiEntry<K, V> entry, @Nullable BiEntry<K, V> oldEntryForKey) {
  int keyBucket = entry.keyHash & mask; // 1
  entry.nextInKToVBucket = hashTableKToV[keyBucket]; // Step 2
  hashTableKToV[keyBucket] = entry; // 3
  ...
}
```

Suppose A completes first, `hashTableKToV[keyBucket]` = A, `A.nextInKToVBucket` = null. when B comes, and completes Step 2, `B.nextInKToVBucket` = A. Suppose before execute step 3, Thread of A is executing `rehashIfNecessary`, and unfortunately rehash is required.

```
private void rehashIfNecessary() {
  BiEntry<K, V>[] oldKToV = hashTableKToV;
  if (Hashing.needsResizing(size, oldKToV.length, LOAD_FACTOR)) {
    int newTableSize = oldKToV.length * 2;

    this.hashTableKToV = createTable(newTableSize);  // Step 4
    ...

    for (BiEntry<K, V> entry = firstInKeyInsertionOrder; 
        entry != null;
        entry = entry.nextInKeyInsertionOrder) {
      insert(entry, entry); // step 5
    }
    ...
  }
}
```

When step 4 is completed, `hashTableKToV` is cleared. It is unlucky that Thread of B execute step 3 in this moment, and `hashTableKToV[keyBucket]` = B. Thread of A continues with step 5, which insert A again, and `A.nextInKToVBucket` = A after step 2, causing a circular reference. And hence infinite loop in `seekByKey`.

Here is an example for how to reproduce above case (not 100%, may need to try several times):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;

import com.google.common.collect.BiMap;
import com.google.common.collect.HashBiMap;

public class HashBiMapConcurrentTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        BiMap<String, String> biMap = HashBiMap.create();
        ExecutorService executors = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4);
        Collection<Callable<Integer>> tasks = new ArrayList<>();
        Callable<Integer> task = () -> {
            for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
                biMap.put("A" + i, "B" + i);
                biMap.get("A" + i);
            }
            System.out.println("Done");
            return 0;
        };
        tasks.add(task);
        tasks.add(task);
        List<Future<Integer>> futures = executors.invokeAll(tasks);
        for (Future<Integer> future : futures) {
            while (!future.isDone()) {
                Thread.sleep(10);
            }
        }
        executors.shutdown();
    }
}
```